# Warning: Use of uninitialized value $count in concatenation (.) or string at p3_in .pl line 34，<SRC> chunk 140

Tags: perl

I cannot figure out why the output complains that `$count` is not initialized, and what should I do?
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Author: Thomas Thiel
# Program name: primer3_in.pl
# Description: creates a PRIMER3 input file based on SSR search results

open (IN,"<$ARGV[0]") || die ("\nError: Couldn't open misa.pl results file (*.misa) !\n\n");

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
$filename =~ s/\.misa//;
open (SRC,"<$filename") || die ("\nError: Couldn't open source file containing original FASTA sequences !\n\n");
open (OUT,">$filename.p3in");

undef $/;
$in = <IN>;
study $in;

$/= ">";

my $count;
while (<SRC>)
  {
  next unless (my ($id,$seq) = /(.*?)\n(.*)/s);
  $seq =~ s/[\d\s>]//g;#remove digits, spaces, line breaks,...
  while ($in =~ /$id\t(\d+)\t\S+\t\S+\t(\d+)\t(\d+)/g)
    {
    my ($ssr_nr,$size,$start) = ($1,$2,$3);
    $count++;
    print OUT "SEQUENCE_ID=$id"."_$ssr_nr\nSEQUENCE_TEMPLATE=$seq\n";
    print OUT "PRIMER_PRODUCT_SIZE_RANGE=100-280\n";
    print OUT "TARGET=",$start-3,",",$size+6,"\n";
    print OUT "PRIMER_MAX_END_STABILITY=250\n=\n"
    };
  };
print "\n$count records created.\n";
```

How can I initialize `$count`?

Comment: adding "use diagnostics" would suggest it's a warning which occurs always when performing stringification of undef value.

Comment: Is this an actual program -- without `use strict;`?  I very strongly recommend to always have that, along with `use warnings;` (better than `-w`).

Comment: It is better to use "lexical" filehandles with `open` than the globs, so: `open my $fh_in,...` instead of `open IN,...`. See [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open)

Comment: Rolled back to a version of the question that does not disqualify the top voted answer.

Comment: Some advices: consider use open with 3 arguments instead 2 (perldoc -f open), consider add `use strict; use warnings;` in your code and check about IO::File module — will help a lot programs like this

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not initialize the `$count` variable; it is undefined.

To initialize `$count` to a numeric value (like 0), change:

```
my $count;
```

to:

```
my $count = 0;
```

Comment: @annxxin _Why became this?_ You changed code or data.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple paths through the code that do not result in `$count++` being called. One or more of these may never be true:

- `while (<SRC>)`
- `unless (my ($id,$seq) = /(.*?)\n(.*)/s)`
- `while ($in =~ /$id\t(\d+)\t\S+\t\S+\t(\d+)\t(\d+)/g)`

Before the first use, unconditionally initialise `$count`. The obvious place would be in the `my $count` statement.

---

`perldoc perlsyn` explains:

> The only things you need to declare in Perl are report formats and
> subroutines (and sometimes not even subroutines). A scalar variable
> holds the undefined value ("undef") until it has been assigned a defined
> value, which is anything other than "undef". When used as a number,
> "undef" is treated as 0; when used as a string, it is treated as the
> empty string, ""; and when used as a reference that isn't being assigned
> to, it is treated as an error. If you enable warnings, you'll be
> notified of an uninitialized value whenever you treat "undef" as a
> string or a number. Well, usually.